# I have blockchain.info wallet with BTC and BCC. What will happen if I send BTC only to that address?

Tags: blockchain.info, trading, bitcoin-cash

Previous question: [In case of the Bitcoin split - when holding BTC on blockchain.info - will I receive coins on both forks?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/57202/in-case-of-the-bitcoin-split-when-holding-btc-on-blockchain-info-will-i-rece)

I know that I can restore private key from the 12 words BIP 39 recovery phrase.

I was silly / stupid / risky enough to move `1.11111111 BTC` pre-fork - https://twitter.com/stefek99/status/891777250089209857 - to ViaBTC and now there is `฿ 1.25469771` post-fork Bitcoin.

I have no idea how to reconcile this. Thinking about splitting my remaining pre-fork Bitcoin, trading BCC for BTC and keeping post-fork balance only.

Sending post-fork BTC to pre-fork BTC and BCC address seems risky. Is there anything I should consider?

https://blockchain.info official statement: https://blog.blockchain.com/2017/07/30/bitcoin-cash-hard-fork-blockchain-users/

Answer (score 1):

At the time of the fork, your previous key now gives you access to two independent wallets one BTC, one BCH. They both start with the amount you had before the fork. There are no "pre-fork" nor "post-fork" bitcoin, there are now only one key opening two different wallets.

The two wallets are not compatible anymore, it means that you cannot move some coins from the BCH wallet to BTC wallet, nor BTC to BCH.

If you send BTC to your BTC wallet, then your BTC wallet will get the coins, and the BCH wallet will stay unchanged.
If you want to fill the BCH wallet also, you have to make another transaction, on the BCH network, of the same amount.

Best pratice would be to separate your BCH wallets from BTC wallets. You can do this with Electron Cash software with the "recovery passphrase", as described here: [https://thebot.net/threads/tutorial-how-to-get-your-private-key-from-blockchain-info-redeem-your-bch-from-blockchain-info.396919/][1]. Don't forget that until you move the coins to new wallets, the same key will give access to both BTC and BCH wallets, even if they have different lives, so keep them safe!